# Google Protocol Buffer serialized string can contain embedded NULL characters in it?

Tags: c++, serialization, null, protocol-buffers, stdstring

I am using Google Protocol Buffer for message serialization. 
This is my sample proto file content.

```
package MessageParam;

message Sample
{
    message WordRec
    {
        optional uint64 id = 1; 
        optional string word = 2;
        optional double value = 3;
    }
    message WordSequence
    {
        repeated WordRec WordSeq = 1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to serialize the message in C++ like following

```
MessageParam::Sample::WordSequence wordseq;
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{
    AddRecords(wordseq.add_wordseq());
}
std::string str = wordseq.SerializeAsString();
```

After executing the above statement, the size of the str is 430. It is having embedded null characters in it. While I am trying to assign this str to std::wstring, std::wstring is terminating when it finds first null character.

```
void AddRecords(MessageParam::Sample::WordRec* wordrec)
{
    int id;
    cin>>id;
    wordrec->set_id(id);
    getline(cin, *wordrec->mutable_word());
    long value;
    cin>>value;
    wordrec->set_value(value);
}
```

Value of wordseq.DebugString() is
*WordSeq {
  id: 4
  word: "software"
  value: 1
}
WordSeq {
  id: 19
  word: "technical"
  value: 0.70992374420166016
}
WordSeq {
  id: 51
  word: "hardware"
  value: 0.626017153263092
}*
How can I serialize "wordseq" as string which contains embedded NULL characters ?

Comment: to be clear, are you saying that you are extracting null characters from `cin`?

Comment: "While I am trying to assign this str to std::wstring", why don't you show the relevant code for that, instead of `AddRecords` function which is apparently totally irrelevant code?

Comment: I am not extracting NULL characters from cin.It is a sample for adding values to wordrec.Actually I am adding values from a list container to this wordrec Following is the actual code
for(int i=0;iter!=end;++i,++iter)
{AddRecords(wordseq.add_wordseq(),iter);}
Here iter is the list iterator.Following is the content of the list
[0]={id=4 string=L"software" value=1.00000000}
[1]={id=19 string=L"technical" value=0.709923744}
.
[14]={id=3150 string=L"recieved" value=0.241736889}
std::string str=std::string(wordseq.SerializeAsString());Value of str after this is "\n\x15\b\x4\x12\bsoftware\x19"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try to store a Protobuf in a `wstring`. `wstring` is for storing unicode text, but a protobuf is not unicode text nor any other kind of text, it is raw bytes. You should keep in in byte form. If you really need to store a Protobuf in a textual context, you should base64-encode it first.

Arguably Protobufs' use of `std::string` to store bytes (rather than text) is confusing. Perhaps it should have used `std::vector<unsigned char>` all along. You should treat protobufs' `std::string`s like you would `std::vector<unsigned char>`.