# How to assign Google protocol buffer SerializeAsString() output which contains embedded nulls to std::string?

Tags: c++, serialization, null, protocol-buffers, stdstring

I am trying to serialize the message as string in C++ using google protocol buffer and assign the serialized result (which contains embedded nulls in it) to std::string. Following is my code:

```
std::string result = message.SerializeAsString();
```

It is ignoring the characters after the first \0 character. result is not having the full serialized string. I tried the following which explicitly specifies the length.

```
int size = message.ByteSize();
std::string result(std::string(message.SerializeAsString()), size);
```

It is also not working for me. Is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is reported if you `cout << result.length();` ?

Comment: The characters are probably not ignored inside the `string` but inside the tool you use to check them.

Comment: @RichardHodges Length of the result is 430. Serialized string is having first null character in its 15'th index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem storing NUL bytes in std::strings. You can just assign the string normally. Both of your code snippets should work fine.

The problem comes if you ever call `.c_str()` and try to pass the string to something expecting `const char*`. At this point, the receiver of the `const char*` doesn't know the size of the string so assumes it ends at the first NUL byte. So, don't do that -- always make sure you're either passing the `std::string` whole, or that your passing both a pointer and a size (from `.size()`).

You commented on another answer that you need to convert to `std::wstring`. EDIT: I moved my comments on this to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30380938/2686899).

Comment: "Both of your code snippets should work fine." 
Actually there is a problem with the snippet OP asked. He is creating an intermediate copy of a string with the string(const char*) version of the constructor. I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Yes. The problem is with std::wstring. I have used const char* instead of converting the serialized string to std::wstring. "always make sure you're either passing the std::string whole, or that your passing both a pointer and a size (from .size())." - It worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @bashrc I don't see where OP is calling `string(const char*)`. `SerializeAsString()` returns `std::string`, not `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string result(message.SerializeAsString(), size);
```

when you are creating the temporary string

> std::string(message.SerializeAsString())

This part consumes the embedded nulls.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
std::string result = std::string(wordseq.SerializeAsString()) is worked for me. Now I need to copy this string to std::wstring. Is it also a null terminated string ? I tried std::wstring finalresult(result.begin(), result.end());

Comment: @Ramya: That doesn't make sense. `std::wstring` is for wide text, outside the narrow character set. If you have embedded nulls, your input is presumably binary not text.

Comment: @MSalters: message value is message {
  id: 4
  word: "software"
  value: 1
}
message {
  id: 19
  word: "technical"
  value: 0.70992374420166016
}
After serialize this to string, the resulted string is having embedded nulls in it.
I need to store the serialized resulted string into wide string

Comment: @bashrc I don't see how that's true. `message.SerializeAsString()` returns `std::string`, not `const char*`, so `std::string(message.SerializeAsString())` is just invoking the regular copy constructor, which has no problem with a string containing NULs.